# Upload half file?

Tags: php, javascript

Is it possible to upload a specific part of the file rather than the whole file? Say, I want to upload only first 100 bytes of the file, or the rest of the file given offset 100 bytes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use javascript **FileApi** with **BlobApi** to upload any part of file. Note, this is a HTML5 feature.

If you want to investigate this features you can look at [jQuery File Upload Plugin](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Comment: Some links to tutorials or other documents would be nice.

Answer (score 2):

In more modern browsers, with the right permissions, yes. You need the browser to support file stream reading. A tutorial is here: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Open the file, find the chunk you want and the POST through AJAX (e.g. with jQuery).

You may find it easier to synchronously upload in chunks and piece together serverside (e.g. with a session) - this way you can give feedback on the upload progress.

Not sure of a method for older browsers, or ones where this is blocked by the user - so you're probably better uploading the entire file (using a FILE post) and stripping out the bit you need serverside. More upload, but better support for everyone.

---

Edit - someone else just posted a question about this: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload  - it doesn't appear to support it natively, but it may also do what you want with some fiddling? You'll still need to handle the fallback, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can use slice method of file api to get half file.

```
var midpt=Math.round(file.size/2);
var halfFile=file.slice(0,midpt); //specify start and end positions
```